# Flink checkpoints keep failing (Timeout while awaiting InitProducerId)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

After digging through many SO posts and even JIRA issues, I don't know where to look anymore.
Every single checkpoint in Flink fails due to timeout, in the exception section for the job it shows following error, however the job itself does not fail:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired after 600000milliseconds while awaiting InitProducerId
```

When disabling checkpointing, everything regarding Kafka works as expected, so my assumption is it may have something to do with the checkpoint waiting for a Kafka commit in order to be acknowledged (`Semantic` is set to `EXACTLY_ONCE`). I remember reading about timeout mismatch leading to problems, so I have aligned the `TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG` in my FlinkKafkaProducer to `900000` milliseconds.

I also tweaked the TransactionTimeout and the MaxBlockMS, as suggested in [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8803) issue, which has a lot of discussion going on right now about this exact same error but apparently no solution.

The Flink book "Stream Processing with Apache Flink" suggests to carefully revise Kafka configurations, e.g. `acks`, `log.flush.interval.messages`, `log.flush.interval.ms` and `log.flush.*`. We already had this working under Flink 1.9.1 though, but since we upgraded to 1.11.1 it does not work anymore. I don't know if somebody touched Kafka settings in the meanwhile, but as far as I can see most of those setting are left to default, except for `log.flush.interval=10000`. We are using Confluent `5.3.3` as before, which means Kafka `2.3.1`.

Also, the Flink job is deployed in a single-node environment, so it should have access to the file system, the whole directory is owned by the user running the Flink service (was a suggested solution in another SO thread).

Does anybody have an idea what causes the failure of those checkpoints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well after having a massive headache about this, I finally found the issue: The Kafka settings *were* in fact altered, as the `transaction.state.log.replication.factor` was lower than the `transaction.state.log.min.isr`, leading to no transaction actually succeeding, as there are never enough in-sync replicas of the Kafka topic.